# How to select a mongo subdocument by id with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm going through a book and the code doesn't work. Everything in google and here indicated that the code is right! It doesn't work

```
Loc
      .findById(req.params.locationid)
      .select('name reviews')
      .exec(
        function(err, location) {
          if (location.reviews && location.reviews.length > 0) {
            // this is the problem:
            review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid); 
            if (!review) {
              sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "reviewid not found"
              });
            } else {
              response = {
                location: {
                  name: location.name,
                  id: req.params.locationid
                },
                review: review
              };
              sendJSONresponse(res, 200, response);
            }
          }
        }
    );
```

The `id` is not a function, so `id()` returns nothing.

I tried hard coding the id number, tired many things that I found online, but the bottom line is that `location.reviews.id` is just a value. I also did `Loc.findById(req.params.locationid).reviews ...`: `where`, `findById`, nothing! I also waisted a lot of time trying `_id` and many things that went with that

I could loop through the reviews and stop if the `reviews.id` match, but I want to know what the author was trying to do.

The way I understand it is that `location` is a javascript object, it's natural not to be able to use the `id` as a function

This is the schema

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: String,
  rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
  reviewText: String,
  createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: {type: String, required: true},
  address: String,
  rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'},
  openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema], //nesting a schema
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
```

---

The entire module code is (I though I'd share it incase I didn't select the right chunk):

```
module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function(req, res) {
  console.log("Getting single review");
  if (req.params && req.params.locationid && req.params.reviewid) {
    Loc
      .findById(req.params.locationid)
      .select('name reviews')
      .exec(
        function(err, location) {
          if (location.reviews && location.reviews.length > 0) {
            review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);
            if (!review) {
              sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "reviewid not found"
              });
            } else {
              response = {
                location: {
                  name: location.name,
                  id: req.params.locationid
                },
                review: review
              };
              sendJSONresponse(res, 200, response);
            }
          }
        }
    );
  } else {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
      "message": "Not found, locationid and reviewid are both required"
    });
  }
};
```

Than you help?

Comment: Please add `Loc` schema in your question? Per this [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), DocumentArrays have a special `id` method for looking up a document by its `_id`

Comment: @zangw I just added the schema. I went through that document so many time and can't get it to work

Comment: Is `req.params.reviewid` valid `ObjectId`? what the value of `req.params.reviewid`?

Comment: @zangw it's just a string. I read about `ObjectId` but not really get it. How do I convert the id string into an `ObjectId`

Comment: Try to wrap it with `var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;` then `ObjectId(req.params.reviewid)`?

Comment: @zangw I ended up with `var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; 
review = location.reviews.id(ObjectId(req.params.reviewid));`, it does not work! Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104760/discussion-between-zangw-and-relidon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion, we found the root cause by

```
db.locations.update({ name: 'Starcups' }, 
                    { $push: { 
                         reviews: { 
                            author: 'Simon Holmes', 
                            id: ObjectId(), // issue is here
                            rating: 5, ... } } })
```

`id: ObjectId()` will create `id` field in the subdocument and without `_id` field in the `reviews` subdocument.

[`id()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) method is used to documentArrays have a special `id` method for looking up a document by its `_id`. Since there is no `_id` field in `reviews` document array, it does not work well.

Please remove `id: ObjectId()` from your code.

Comment: I finally added new subdocuments and the result is perfect. I spent hours on this problem. And what's funny (now that's all over) the book has it as `id: ObjectId()` and makes no the id() being a getter  for _id. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this as the example on page 151 of Getting MEAN by Simon Holmes.  The problem is that there is a tiny error in the book.  The name "id" in the above $push instruction should be "_id".  Make this change and everything works.  The above suggestion that you simply delete id: ObjectId() is incorrect.