# Can't take id of subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: mongoose

***Whole document***

```
{
   "_id": "5952e97a833244f2f94f1243",
   "name": "Starcups",
   "reviews": [
      {
         "author": "Simon Holmes",
         "id": "5952ea74833244f2f94f1244",
         "rating": 5,
         "timestamp": "2013-07-15T21:00:00.000Z",
         "reviewText": "What a great place.",
         "createdOn": "2017-07-02T00:32:40.449Z"
      },
      {
         "author": "Charlie Chaplin",
         "id": "5952eb61833244f2f94f1245",
         "rating": 3,
         "timestamp": "2013-07-15T21:00:00.000Z",
         "reviewText": "It was okay.",
         "createdOn": "2017-07-02T00:32:40.449Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have an issue to take id of the subdocument in MongoDB. When I'm trying to show any other object of subdocument it is working fine.

For example

```
reviews[0].author
```

Would show me "Simon Holmes" value.

But

```
reviews[0].id
```

Would show **Null**

What to do? Without searching by id in subdocument I can't return an object that needed.

Comment: You tagged the question with "mongoose", which means that it's likely the property is actually named `_id`, since mongoose creates that property in sub-document schemas by default. For you to have a property named `id` instead you would have had to explicitly specify that in your schema, as well as specifically suppress the creation of `_id`. So it's likely actually called `_id`.

Comment: No, I don't know why but actually it is named `id`. With `_id` it is showing nothing.

Comment: Then your schema is incorrect where applied to an imported source. Use `reviews[0].get('id')`. That is how you access properties not declared in the attached schema to the model. You should probably also convert the data to match the schema or change the schema to match the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns Null, the same as with just reviews[0].id

Comment: That is interesting. Notably it's `null` rather then`undefined` which would instead be returned for a property that did not exist at all. Mongoose "aliases" `id` for `_id` so I think this is where it is getting lost. Adding to the schema does fix this. Also adding [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to return plain objects will allow you to access the property just how you originally tried. Like I started with though, you need to either fix the data or schema as a more permanent solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and help. Just need to make data without 'id' and it would be with '_id' by the standard. It is the just small error in the tutorial. I have found the same problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677141/how-to-select-a-mongo-subdocument-by-id-with-mongoose